# What does the phrase “to be only able to do X for subset Y is unacceptable” mean?

Tags: conditionals

What does the phrase “to be only able to do X for subset Y is unacceptable” mean?

Does it mean that the speaker is against doing X?
Or that they think effort should be made to expand X for other subsets?

If you want to stick with the pure language discussion and avoid the political correctness and ethics involved do not read below.

The question actually came as an argument whether the author of the phrase “To be only able to offer a product to one part of population is inequitable and should be unacceptable to the field” meant to say that the product should not be released as is or whether she called for more research. The phrase is from this article: https://www.technologyreview.com/s/612322/white-people-only-dna-tests-show-how-unequal-science-has-become/

Comment: She is saying two contradicting things - hence the dilemma: on the one hand she says that the product should be withheld until it can be made available to the entire population; on the other hand she says that the product should be released now, because it can save lives.

Comment: I read it as an implicit suggestion that doing X is worthwhile, though that suggestion might be overruled by other things in the context; and an explicit statement that doing it only for Y is unacceptable. The writer says that this state should not continue, but leaves it completely open how to fix it. They probably do mean  "If it X cannot be extended beyond Y then it shouldn't be done at all",  but might mean other things.

Comment: How could that mean speaker, audience or anyone else was “against” anything, or that effort should be made to expand X (for other subsets)?

If you want to move from a pure language discussion and look at political correctness or ethics, why not post the same wording on sites dealing with those?

Comment: I don't want to move to the political correctness or ethics. I want to understand the meaning of the sentence. From PC POV though the meaning of the sentence is very relevant. Still the argument is very much a linguistic one. Also I would like to understand the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting, because the placement of "only" can be very confusing, and is supposed to adhere to strict rules regarding its position in the sentence. However, most speakers of English do not stick to these rules, as their meaning is generally obvious when other clues, such as context are taken into account.

I would assume here that the speaker believes that X should be made available to other subsets, not just Y. However, I can only tell that by looking at the actual sentence and its context.

Here what the speaker should have said is:

> "To be able to do X for only subset Y is unacceptable"

This is because "only" should be placed as close as possible to the word or phrase that it modifies. However, like most speakers of English, the speaker here is not conforming to this rather strict rule, as the meaning can be gleaned from the context. Also, sticking blindly to this rule can sometimes make speech sound a little archaic (IMO).

For some more examples, see this website: https://getitwriteonline.com/articles/placement-of-only/

Comment: Would your answer change if X cannot physically be made available for other subsets?

Comment: Perhaps, but again it would depend on context. In this context it seems like people are working to get X available for other subsets.